# Converting image datatype from Sql Server to php

Tags: php, sql-server, image, jpeg

I'm trying to show an image saved from SQL Server from the database to the php page I am creating. What I've done so far is I get the necessary data from the database, which is the image , and the image type(if its a jpg).

This is what I did:

```
            $idata = base64_decode($imageResult);
            imagejpeg($idata);
```

But it is showing an error of the following:

```
 imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given [APP\Controller\MainController.php, line 226]
```

How do I make the image show inside my php? Do I need to decode the data that I'm getting from the database before I could convert it?

I want to give an example but the data that I currently have is very sensitive, which is why I don't know how I could give an example.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `imagecreatefromstring` function:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

```
$idata = base64_decode($imageResult);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($idata)
imagejpeg($image);
```